# AVPlayer not playing iPod-Library song item in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am accessing the songs using MPMediaItem from iPod Library and saving the assetURL in my coredata then I am using the following code to play the sound but it doesn't plays the sound.

```
  var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(file as String)
    print("FILE :   \(file)  \n")
    var error: NSError?
    var itemPlayer:AVPlayer?
   // itemPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: file as String))
    itemPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: file as String)))
    itemPlayer!.play()
```

and it just print the following but player is not playing the song

```
FILE :   ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=4287130341014298234
```

And also if i use AVAudioPlayer to initialize player using above assetURL then it return me Nil. and i think this is because the above url is not local it should be like file://....   . So what should i do to play sound using assetURL of song from iPod Library

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to play a music file in your iPod library and already using MPMediaItem you should try using `MPMusicPlayerController`.

Alternatively, if you wanted to continue with way you were doing, you could do this (this is assuming that your `file` variable is the `MPMediaItem`):

```
 var fileUrl = file.assestURL
 var myPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: fileURL)
 itemPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: myPlayerItem)
```

Comment: have you check the second method yourself. here the main issue is fileUrl is like   ipod-library:// ...........      But for AVPlayerItem it should be like this file:///.........     so in the above case myPlayerItem will be nill